# react.js without node.js unable to include the component class available in external file

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning react. Not using Node.js though

```js
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
          return ( 
            <p>Hello, {this.props.name}! </p>
          );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld name="Narayanan Arumugam" />,         
                document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

The above code works fine. Now how to add the Javascript piece of code to an external file and call it like scripts.js and include it in the index.html.

I tried adding it in a separate file; had a scripts.js file at the same directory level as the index.html and placed the JavaScript code inside it.
Tried using the file with the below command.

`<script type="text/babel" src="scripts.js"></script>`

However I got a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

I want to be able to separate my classes

Comment: check this answer it worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503939/can-i-use-es-modules-in-browser-with-babel-without-bundling-my-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) please add something like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
```

(2) all works for me with index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src='c-s.js' type="text/babel"></script>
```

and c-s.js

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return ( 
        <p>Hello, {this.props.name}! </p>
      );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld name="Narayanan Arumugam" />,         
            document.getElementById("container"));
```

(3) when you just run index.html, you will get security error at console and blank screen, like this

```
Fetching scripts with an invalid type/language attributes is deprecated and will be removed in M56, around January 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5760718284521472 for more details.

browser.js:5773 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/sbt-dudkin-av/src/domize-0/c-s.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.  transform.load @ browser.js:5773
```

(4) if you need this work, load it from server (for instance, install node and http-server and run 'http-server' at folder with you code, and then run 'localhost:8085' at browser)

Comment: yes i have included the babel-core. yet getting a blank page.

Comment: so i got that you did not post all your code. please fix it

Comment: finally had to install node and get this working. thanks :)