# Using react with normal HTML/JavaScript to run without using npm/node

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angularjs, web-applications

Suppose you have an application that was developed using the Java Spring framework and deployed on a Tomcat server, also, the application uses AngularJS for most of the front-end application parts.

I am thinking of using React to add HTML components to customize the front-end parts of the application instead of using AngularJs. I did follow React tutorials and realized that you need to have node and npm installed and spin up a server to run the application using `npm run start` to preview the React Web Application. I wonder how you can include "React components" on a regular `HTML/JavaScript` page and run this component on the browser without the need to use `npm run start`. I am trying to avoid the need to install node/npm on the target machine where the Java Spring-based web application is running.

I don't plan to integrate AngularJS with React. All I want to do is to add React `HTML/JSX` components since I noticed it is much easier than Angular in general.

Is it possible to include the needed libraries for React dependencies along with the target application using the `script` tag on the main `index.htm` web page then I can start adding React components as usual?

After installing the react sample project using `npx create-react-app react-prj` you get the below `index.js` and a bunch of other libraries and application parts:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And you get the below main HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned, if you open the above HTML in the browser, you will get an empty page, and you must run the app using `npm run start`.

How I can get a setup for a sample React web application without using node/npm and I just want to use a normal HTML/JavaScript application to be run on the browser directly?

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I am aware this isn’t possible but you could try using Vue for that case, as you should be able to import Vue from CDN right into your HTML/JS files without the need of installing any node modules whatsoever.

Comment: This might help you https://devpractical.com/use-react-without-nodejs/

Comment: Thank you @Sean ... I found the answer and posted it below. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sean. Also, I found a good reference here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504616/4180447

I managed to implement React without npm as follows:

- Create the sample app using `npx create-react-app sample-prj` as usual.
- Modify the HTML and JavaScript files as follows:

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/App.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/index.css">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/App.js" type="text/babel"  data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" defer ></script>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

/src/App.js

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
// import './App.css';

function App() {
  const logo = '../src/logo.svg';
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React xxx
        </a>
        <div>This is a test with Tarek and Firas</div>
      </header>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
      <div>This is a test with Tarek and Firas</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

/src/index.js

```
// import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import '/src/index.css';
import App from '/src/App.js';
// import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
// reportWebVitals();
```